# Redirecting to record with slug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I implemented a very simple *slugification* for my article model:

```
# app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
def show
    @article = Article.find_by(slug: params[:slug])
end

# config/routes.rb
resources :articles, param: :slug
```

And it works almost fine. But there is one problem:

```
  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article  # <- here is the problem 
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

This `redirect_to` redirects to `articles/:id`  instead of `articles/:slug`.

Where do I have to configure that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either override the `Article#to_param` method, or can use a more explicit redirect target (recommended).

replace:

```
redirect_to @article
```

With:

```
redirect_to article_path(@article.slug)
# or:
redirect_to article_path(slug: @article.slug)
```

The `to_param` method will change how the model behaves in Rails, which might be what you need if you want to be able to pass the records directly to `form_for` (and other builders).
You can either [override it at the instance level](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Integration.html#method-i-to_param), or you can use [the class level helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Integration/ClassMethods.html#method-i-to_param).

Answer (score 1):

Create new route:

```
# config/routes.rb
get 'articles/:slug', to: 'articles#show', as: :article_with_slug
```

And use it:

```
# app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)
  if @article.save!
    redirect_to article_with_slug(slug: @article.slug) 
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```